Join multiple rows from a table in SQL query where the dates and the shifts are the same
I am using this SQL query to collect and analyze shift production data. The result of the query gives me almost what I want but not quite as the infeed, outfeed, and scrap counts are in separate rows.
How do I join the rows so that for each shift in a day there is only one row that contains all three values?
Current table
Desired table:



Shift
tag
count
date
tag2
count2
tag3
count3




C
scrap
2284
10/14
outfeed
14862
infeed
17152


B
scrap
1693
10/14
outfeed
29117
infeed
30828


A
scrap
1498
10/13
outfeed
33891
infeed
35280



Current code:
SELECT shift, tag, "count", TO_CHAR(capturetime, 'MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') AS "Datetime" ,TO_CHAR(capturetime, 'MM/DD') AS "Date"
FROM shift_data.production_counts
WHERE machine = 'SGP3'
and tag like '%Reason:Total%'
and capturetime >= (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - '8 days'::interval)
and capturetime <= CURRENT_Date 
and (  (cast(TO_CHAR(capturetime, 'HH24') as int)=6 and cast(TO_CHAR(capturetime, 'MI') as int)>45) 
    or (cast(TO_CHAR(capturetime, 'HH24') as int)=7 and cast(TO_CHAR(capturetime, 'MI') as int)<1) 
    or (cast(TO_CHAR(capturetime, 'HH24') as int)=18 and cast(TO_CHAR(capturetime, 'MI') as int)>45) 
    or (cast(TO_CHAR(capturetime, 'HH24') as int)=19 and cast(TO_CHAR(capturetime, 'MI') as int)<1)
) 
order by capturetime DESC

I don't know how to join to the same table.

Which dbms are you using? (The above query is product specific in several ways.)

As @jarlh said, this depends on which dbms you are using, PIVOT for SQL Server, CrosTab for PostgreSQL, a custom query for MySQL

A [mcve] is supposed to include both sample table data and the expected result.

Are you interested in three particular tags or can these be three different tags from day to day?

Which RDBMS are you using (MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server, something else)? Please add the tag of your database to your question. See this to know why tagging is important.

If I got right what you described in your question, this may help you.
Since I don't have your database structure, here a quick example.
Let's say that this is our table:
CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `father` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mother` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
)

Insert a father, a mother and a child:
INSERT INTO `person` (`id`, `name`, `father`, `mother`) VALUES
(1, 'John', NULL, NULL),
(2, 'Jessica', NULL, NULL),
(3, 'Max', 1, 2)

Now you can select every person with a father and a mother using two joins to the table we're selecting from:
SELECT
   `person`.`id`,
   `person`.`name`,
   `father`.`name` AS 'father',
   `mother`.`name` AS 'mother'
FROM `person`
JOIN `person` AS `father` ON `father`.`id` = `person`.`father`
JOIN `person` AS `mother` ON `mother`.`id` = `person`.`mother`

The key is to name both joins (here father and mother)
The result then is:



id
name
father
mother




3
Max
John
Jessica



